# Prove that gcd(a,b)=dgcd(a/d,b/d).

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

[image]

I think the strategy for this problem would be i assume some arbitrary element is in gcd(a,b) and chase it into the rhs and then do it the other way around , but i am not sure how to even start this one.

Comment: Use the fact that $\gcd(u,v)$ is the smallest positive number in $\{ux+vy:x,y\in\mathbb Z\}$.

Comment: so would i have gcd(a,b)=ax+by=ax/d+by/d=dgcd(a/d,b/d)? how would the other direction go?

Answer (score 0):

We can rephrase the conditions as
$a=p\cdot d$ and $b=q\cdot d$ with $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$.

Then
$$\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(pd,qd)=d\cdot\gcd(p,q)=d\cdot\gcd(\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d})$$

Comment: Yes but the second equality is really what the OP is trying to prove.